# How to convert key-value pairs to object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to form values to object/array like `var date = {"first_name": "X", "last_name": "Y"};`

I am using `data = $(form).serialize()` but it is produce `first_name:X,last_name:Y`

If I am using `data = $(form).serializeArray()` then it is taking other values too like select all options, so it is wrong.

So how to convert above key-value pairs to object using JavaScript?

Comment: Consider using `split`, and `reduce`. Also, may you show your effort?

Comment: unclear please make a minimal example as recommended

Comment: `$.serialize()` wont return something like `first_name:X,last_name:Y`. It's only purpose is to built a valid key-value-pair string for submission: `first_name=x&last_name=Y&...`

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form))`

Comment: serializeArray should work fine

Answer (score 1):

`serialize()` is used to encode form data into URLs. Instead, use the `FormData` object.

```
const formdata = new FormData($("#formId"));
```